# How many attacks do I have in a standard action with natural weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, natural-weapon

So I have a Toothy Half-Orc with claws - all primary weapons. In a full round action I can do 1 bite(1d4) and 2 claw(1d6) attacks.

> Primary attacks are made using the creature’s full base attack bonus and add the creature’s full Strength bonus on damage rolls.
>   (...)
>   If a creature has only one type of attack, but has multiple attacks per round, that attack is treated as a primary attack, regardless of its type.

But how many attacks do I get in a standard action? I really can't find anything specific in the description of [natural attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks).

Based on the info, I seems that I can do one move action and make 3 x attacks.

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During a given turn in combat, characters generally have access to a standard action, move action, swift action, and many free actions. **Using your standard action to attack only gives you 1 attack, even if your base attack bonus or number of natural weapons would give you multiple.** To use those multiple attacks, you must use both your standard *and* move action as a full round attack.

Answer (score 3):

Standard actions are almost always singular attacks; natural weapons are not an exception. The standard-action Attack option simply allows you to make one attack with one weapon; that weapon can be natural or manufactured, but it’s still just one attack.